# How to prove that $2-1+3-2+4-3+…+(n+1) - n = -1 + (n+1)$?

Tags: summation

How can I prove that $2-1+3-2+4-3+…+(n+1) - n = -1 + (n + 1)$?

I know that $2$ and $-2$ cancel out, and so do $3$ and $-3$, $4$ and $-4$, and so on, but is there a way I can prove that in such a sum, every term is cancelled out **except** the second term and the second to last term? (In this example, $-1$ and $n + 1$.)

Actually, is merely saying that most of the terms cancel out enough?

$n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @Victor thanks, it does look like my sum is a "telescoping series". That's something I had never heard! (I'm just in the first year of high school.)

Comment: For this particular sum another way is to write it like this: $(2-1)+(3-2)+(4-3)+\cdots+((n+1)-n)$, and simplify the things in parentheses before summing. But in general it's very useful to know about telescoping series.